# Use X desktop apps using another users on my own account, like with root

Tags: linux, display, desktop, root, user

It's possible run apps from command line like root using "su root" , and later executing the app, like firefox, and works, using the data from root home. But why I can't do it with another users using "su user" ? The rest trow me one error: "  No  protocol specified . Cant open display"
Thanks you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo will have to allow the new user to access your X server.

```
     xhost +
```

must be issued before `su name_of_2nd_user`.

Comment: Thanks you, in reality not resolve my problem directly : use xhost +username give me a "xhost:  bad hostname "username"" , but give me the clue for found the solution: I can use "xhost +" without nothing more for activate acess to the rest of users to my Xserver