# GUI can't start while redhat6 is lcoked

Tags: linux, redhat-enterprise-linux, gui, lock-screen, xlock

We are on redhat6. I've got the command line to start a GUI which I want to be run before I come in for the day, so that my working setup is loaded by that time (sadly I've no control over the fact that this has to be done every day).

When I test manually or schedule via cron when my machine is unlocked everything works fine.
When I test with the system locked the GUI does not load.
There are no cores. The only thing that gets printed on screen is:
No protocol specified
Error: Can't open display:

Any idea on what's going on, or at least how to debug it?
I'd rather not have to kill/unlock xlock just to launch GUIs while I'm not yet in the office.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use X desktop apps using another users on my own account, like with root](https://superuser.com/questions/688420/use-x-desktop-apps-using-another-users-on-my-own-account-like-with-root)

Answer (score 0):

The fix is:
xlock -allowaccess